# Write the correct robots txt file

Tags: robots.txt

I have a webshop on my test domain, no one knows it. I always store the search-es on the site into a search sql table, and there are always search-es with same words. Maybe a robot?

How can I fix this? What should I write into the robots.txt? What folders or links should I disable in the file?

My robots txt looks like:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /cms
Sitemap: http://www.my-domain.hu/sitemap.xml
Host: www.my-domain.hu
```

Sorry for bad english, I hope you understand what I write. :)

**Update:**

And what about this robotx file? Is it correct? What is MJ12bot?

```
  User-agent: *
Disallow: /admin/
Disallow: /index.php?route=checkout*
Disallow: /cache/*/block/
Disallow: /custom/*/cache/block/
Disallow: /cib.php
Disallow: /cib_facebook.php
Disallow: /index.php?route=product/relatedproducts/
Disallow: /index.php?route=product/similar_products/
Disallow: /index.php?route=module/upsale/
Disallow: /.well-known/
Allow: /
Sitemap: http://mydomain.hu/sitemap.xml

User-Agent: MJ12bot
Disallow: /
```

Comment: Why don’t you disallow everything?

Comment: Everything? So, google to? Or how do you mean it?

Comment: I updated my post with an another robots file.

Comment: Why not every bot (including Google)? It is a test domain, not meant to be indexed by search engines, no?

Comment: The test domain is meant to be, yes. But if i put this webshop out into an another domain(the customers domain), what would be there with the robots file?

Comment: I would use a different robots.txt file for your test site (if you don’t want to do it manually, you might want to add some server-side logic to output different robots.txt depending on the domain).

Answer (score 0):

To exclude all robots from accessing anything under the root

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

To allow all crawlers complete access

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

Alternatively, you can skip creating a robots.txt file, or create one with empty content.
To exclude a single robot

```
User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow: /
```

This will disallow Google’s crawler from the entire website.

To allow just Google crawler

```
User-agent: Google
Disallow:

User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Is the basic idea. Does that work for you?

Source: https://www.wst.space/allow-disallow-robots-txt/

Comment: User-agent: *
Disallow:
Sitemap: {{ site.url }}/sitemap.xml
------>robots.txt file content the above line but still google dose not give any Details.. can you help me @Anonymous Platypus

Comment: @Goli Please register your website at: https://www.google.com/webmasters/verification/  and upload your sitemap at the section provided. Then try after one or two days